# Milti-insert in MongoDB. Which way is more efficient?

Tags: performance, mongodb

```
// first approach
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  db.testdata.insert({number: i});
}

// second approach
for (var i = 0, arr = []; i < 1000000; i++) {
  arr.push({number: i});
}
db.testdata.insert(arr);
```

Which way is more efficient? Does the second approach make a single request to the database?

Comment: the bottom way should be better , it uses less query. This seems like a test query, i think you should go with "second approach"

Comment: Neither way, you should use the bulkinset API: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/84922794768/mongodbs-new-bulk-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely the second one will be way faster for big number of inserts. This is because you will make only one db call.

But it is not hard to test it yourself.

```
var X = 100000;
var start = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < X; i++) {
  db.coll1.insert({number: i});
}
var time1 = new Date() - start;
```

And the second one

```
var start = new Date();
for (var i = 0, arr = []; i < X; i++) {
  arr.push({number: i});
}
db.coll2.insert(arr);
var time2 = new Date() - start;
```

And as it was suggested in the comments, you can try [bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/) insert (which in my opinion is doing the same as 2, but I might be wrong):

```
var start = new Date();
var bulk = db.coll3.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (var i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    bulk.insert({number: i});
}
bulk.execute();
var time3 = new Date() - start;
```

**And here are results** for my machine `time1 = 33846`, `time2 = 2191` and`time3 = 2203`.

As you see the difference between 2 and 3 is negligible, but 1 is almost 15 times longer (if you will increase X it will be way bigger). If I were you, I would use documented bulk insert.

Comment: It seems that method 2 and 3 have been unified in later versions of MongoDB. Previously method 2 used to do a batch insert which was a legacy API inferior to BulkInsert but it seems that has been gotten rid of now