# Faster way to build inverted list in Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, upsert, spring-mongo

I want to build inverted list in my MongoDB collection.
Collections looks like this:

```
{ "word" : 2, "docToPos" : { "1" : [ 0 ] } }
{ "word" : 5, "docToPos" : { "1" : [ 1 ] } }
{ "word" : 1, "docToPos" : { "1" : [ 2 ], "2" : [ 1 ] } }
{ "word" : 9, "docToPos" : { "2" : [ 2, 43, 1246 ] } }
```

`word` is some id from dictionary and `docToPos` is map `document` to `position` - eg word 2 is in document 1 at position 1, and word 9 is in document 2 at positions 2, 43 and 1246.

Every new document which I want to add to database is simply an array with word id's:

```
[23, 43, 75, 18, ... ]
```

So using spring-mongo I have this java-code:

```
for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
  invertedListDao.upsert(array[i], documentId, i);
}
```

(upsert method is implemented by me)

This solution works, but if document has 100 000 words it takes 100 000 queries to mongo.

So finally, my question is: is thera a way to do this faster? Eg: query the whole array at once and execute this in db? I know there is `eval` function in `mongo`, but there isn't one in `mongo-spring`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to improve performance would be to use [bulk upserts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/).

```
var bulk = db.invertedListDao.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
  bulk.find({...}).upsert().replaceOne({...})
}
bulk.execute();
```

The reason why it is more efficient and what kind of speed boost you can expect are outlined in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29386756/1090562) but basically you will be doing **only 1 call** to mongo no matter how many words you have.

I am not familiar with java spring mongo, but my rudimentary search [suggests that it is supported](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/com/mongodb/BulkWriteOperation.html) and I hope you will be able to find how to implement bulk upserts in your java driver.

**P.S.** And with the help of Bartektartanus, here is the [link to official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/).

Comment: For 10 000 words it's about 10 times faster than sending each upsert query individually! :) Thanks!

Comment: @bartektartanus glad that it gave significant boost. The more words you will have - the higher the boost will be.